# Getting the I2C Address from a Max9744 amplifier

Tags: i2c

[image]I just bought 2 Max9744 amplifiers that I wish to scan the I2C addresses, just to check against what is said in documentation. I have the amplifier powered with a 12 v supply and the Arduino powered via usb. I run an I2Cscanner it says Devices found: in the serial monitor but doesn't say the address. The wiring is correct and the 5 v supply is giving 5 V. So what gives?
Thank you
Andrew

Comment: Please show exactly, what the Serial Monitor shows (copy and paste it into the question and then format it as text). Also provide a link to the scanner sketch, that you used (or also put it into your question). And please show, how you have connected the Max9744, as it seems to be possible to deactivate I2C by setting the address pins to low.

Comment: The Serial Monitor exactly says "Devices Found: " but then nothing else. Link to I2C scanner https://www.elithecomputerguy.com/2019/07/find-i2c-addresses-on-arduino-i2c-scanner. I will add the images in a second

Comment: Link to datasheet for the Max9744 amplifier?

Comment: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX9744.pdf